# I am getting error when i use middleman command when am trying to add the js and css files in the build

Tags: ruby, backbone.js, coffeescript, haml, middleman

Need Assistance on the below points

1.When am trying to run middleman command I am facing this problem can anyone please help in this
issue
2. And I have added slick.js in my js folder and tried running the build I can able to see the js file but content it is not referring
2. need to add CSS file also

please help me in the above points

```
C:\interface_project>middleman
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
thor (< 2.0, >= 0.17.0)
rack (< 3, >= 1.4.5)
activesupport (< 5.1, >= 3.1, >= 4.2)
addressable (> 2.3)
listen (> 3.0.0)
sass (>= 3.4)
execjs (< 3, >= 0.3.0, > 2.0)
concurrent-ruby (> 1.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
C:/interface_project/config.rb:13:in evaluate_configuration!': undefined methodcompass_config' for #Middleman::ConfigContext:0x000000047f2a70 (NoMethodErro
r)
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/middleman-core-4.2.1/lib/mid
dleman-core/application.rb:329:in instance_eval' from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/middleman-core-4.2.1/lib/mid dleman-core/application.rb:329:inevaluate_configuration!'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/middleman-core-4.2.1/lib/mid
dleman-core/application.rb:286:in initialize' from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.2.1/bin/midd leman:49:innew'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.2.1/bin/midd
leman:49:in ' from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/middleman:22:inload'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/middleman:22:in `
```

Below is the config.rb you can see the below code 
    config.rb

```
###
# Compass
###

# Susy grids in Compass
# First: gem install compass-susy-plugin
# require 'susy'

# Change Compass configuration
# require 'compass'
require 'premailer'

compass_config do |config|
  config.output_style = :nested
  config.line_comments = false
end


set :haml, :attr_wrapper => "\""

###
# Page options, layouts, aliases and proxies
###

# Per-page layout changes:
#
# With no layout
# page "/path/to/file.html", :layout => false
#
# With alternative layout
# page "/path/to/file.html", :layout => :otherlayout
#
# A path which all have the same layout
# with_layout :admin do
#   page "/admin/*"
# end

# Make sure that all partials are rendered without a layout
page "/partials/*", :layout => false


page "/orders.html", :layout => "layout-dealer"
page "/dashboard.html", :layout => "layout-dealer"
# Proxy (fake) files
# page "/this-page-has-no-template.html", :proxy => "/template-file.html" do
#   @which_fake_page = "Rendering a fake page with a variable"
# end

###
# Helpers
###

# set :attr_wrapper, "\""

# Refresh pages automatically
activate :livereload

# Automatic image dimensions on image_tag helper
activate :automatic_image_sizes

# Methods defined in the helpers block are available in templates
helpers do

  # Print an array of string values as a text list
  def text_list(listtext,sep1=", ", sep2=" or ")
    n = listtext.size
    if n > 1
      if n == 2
        (listtext.first(n-1)).join(sep1) + sep2 + listtext.last
      else
        (listtext.first(n-1)).join(sep1) + sep1 + sep2 + listtext.last
      end
    else
      listtext.first
    end
  end

end

set :css_dir, 'assets/css'

set :js_dir, 'assets/js'

set :images_dir, 'assets/images'

module PreMailer
  class << self
    def registered(app)
      require "premailer"
      app.after_build do |builder|
        prefix = build_dir + File::SEPARATOR
        Dir.chdir(build_dir) do
          Dir.glob('email-template.html') do |file|
            premailer = Premailer.new(file, :warn_level => Premailer::Warnings::SAFE, :adapter => :nokogiri, :preserve_styles => true, :remove_comments => true, :remove_ids => true)
            fileout = File.open(file, "w")
            fileout.puts premailer.to_inline_css
            fileout.close
            # FileUtils.cp file, prefix+'email-build/'
            premailer.warnings.each do |w|
              builder.say_status :premailer, "#{w[:message]} (#{w[:level]}) may not render properly in #{w[:clients]}"
            end
            builder.say_status :premailer, prefix+file
          end
        end
      end
    end
    alias :included :registered
  end
end

::Middleman::Extensions.register(:inline_premailer, PreMailer)
# activate :inline_premailer

# Build-specific configuration
set :build_dir, "public"

# Build-specific configuration
configure :build do
  # For example, change the Compass output style for deployment
  # activate :minify_css

  # Minify Javascript on build
  # activate :minify_javascript, :ignore => /locale/

  # Enable cache buster
  # activate :cache_buster

  # Use relative URLs
  activate :relative_assets

  # Compress PNGs after build
  # First: gem install middleman-smusher
  # require "middleman-smusher"
  # activate :smusher

  # Or use a different image path
  # set :http_path, "/Content/images/"

  # ignore the build directory for emails
  ignore 'email-build/*'
  ignore 'node_modules/*'
  ignore 'server.coffee'
  ignore 'web.config'
end
```

Comment: Please include source of `C:/interface_project/config.rb`

Comment: Yes I have included the config.rb code

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with Slick.js... that error is telling you compass_config is undefined.

Try this:

add `gem "middleman-compass"` to your Gemfile

run `bundle install`

If that doesn't fix it, try placing `activate :compass` before your `compass_config do |config|` block.